# How to check continuously which app is opened in foreground from my app's foreground service?

Tags: java, android, performance, service

I want to make a app which starts a foreground service to check which are other app  are running at any time.

started services and running some logic part in different thread. Created notification and a timer (loop ) which check running apps at every 100 millisecond.

```
@Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

  new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    startInForeground();
   }
  }.start();


  return START_STICKY;
 }

 private void startInForeground() {
  createNotification();
  startTimer();

 }
```

startTimer() function is below, which is checking any app is running in background. Everything is fine, i am able to detect which app is running.

```
public void startTimer() {
  ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
   .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    checkAnyAppOpen();
   }
  }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

 }
```

**My concern is**- I have to run **checkAnyAppOpen()** function again and again for infinite period of time. So is it good ? or is there any other way to handle it.
What is impact of this method?.

**My second question is**-  I am able to stop my service but still timer(scheduler) is running continuously. How can i stop it ?. How can it affect if it not stopped as i have to again restart my service after some period of time which may run 5 hour to 24 hour. I have to again do stop and restart.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe for your use-case it is applicable. Just make sure there are no leaks and the service is closed properly.
2. Use `scheduler.shutdown()` to stop executor.